# Why would Quake run slowly in DOS on a modern, 2017 i5 CPU?

Tags: performance, ms-dos, freedos, vesa

I noticed back in the DOS gaming era that DOS games ran slowly in hi-res modes. I was surprised to discover that this could be true on a modern machine.

I booted a 2017 i5 7200u (I think) laptop into [FreeDOS](https://www.freedos.org) and loaded Quake; predictably no sound but otherwise okay. However, in 1280x1024, it ran slowly, which seemed impossible.

I was aware that the processor has to switch between real and protected mode quite a bit, but I doubt that's the problem because I created a virtual machine, running on the CPU, and got Quake to run well in that resolution.

So, what is the bottleneck? The graphics chip? The CSM?

Comment: Because the processor is running a DOS emulator and is doing all the graphics.

Comment: It isn't, freedos is an actual OS

Comment: “So, what is the bottleneck?” - The application itself. When Quake was first published, programmers had to do some interesting tricks, with internal clocks which act weird when processors are 100x faster 2 and half decades later.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I feel this kind of question can be better addressed on the [Retrocomputing SE](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/) site.